# MudDatePicker doesn't change culture date dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, mudblazor

```
@page "/DatePicker"


<MudButton @onclick='() => ChangeDatePicker("FA")' Variant="@variantfa" Color="Color.Primary">FA</MudButton>
<MudButton @onclick='() => ChangeDatePicker("ENG")' Variant="@varianteng" Color="Color.Primary">ENG</MudButton>

<MudDatePicker @ref="_picker"  DateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd" />


@code {
MudDatePicker _picker;

public DateTime? date = DateTime.Today;

public CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

private string language = "ENG";

private Variant variantfa = Variant.Outlined;
private Variant varianteng = Variant.Outlined;

private async Task ChangeDatePicker(string language)
{
    if (language == "FA")
    {
        culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fa-IR");
        _picker.Culture = culture;

        _picker.Date = date;
        _picker.Label = "Persian";
        _picker.TitleDateFormat = "dddd, dd MMMM";

        variantfa = Variant.Filled;
        varianteng = Variant.Outlined;
    }
    else
    {
        culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
        _picker.Culture = culture;
        _picker.Date = date;
        _picker.Label = ""; 

        varianteng = Variant.Filled;
        variantfa = Variant.Outlined;
    }
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

}

in the code above I'm trying to change my date picker culture from the Persian calendar to Gregorian but the problem is that the calendar glitches and it seems like it doesn't change its culture

[here is when I change my date to Persian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBGHW.png)

[and here is when I turn it back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur0oH.png)

I tried
statehaschanged and even and individual function to set each calendar

Comment: As a workaround you coud use two DatePicker and display them according to the selected culture https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckmeEGwAHYqDoBjT

Comment: @Uerschel yeah I did that but I want to make it dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@key is a directive in Blazor that causes the component to be re-rendered and its state to be refreshed.
When @key is placed on a component, every time the value of @key changes, that component will be re-rendered.
So when we set the value of an int or bool as @key and then change that int(bool), the component will be re-rendered.
This causes the state and content of the component to be refreshed.
So by changing @key we can force a component to re-render and refresh its state.
This is very useful for things like refreshing a DatePicker after changing the Culture.

```
@using System.Globalization
@using System.Reflection
<MudSwitch T="bool" Color=@Color.Primary Checked=@IsPersian CheckedChanged=CultureChanged Label=@(IsPersian?"Persian":"English") />

<MudDatePicker Culture="SelectedCulture" @bind-Date="@Date" @key=datePickerState />
@code {
    bool datePickerState = false;
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsPersian { get; set; }
    private void CultureChanged()
    {
        IsPersian = !IsPersian;
        datePickerState = !datePickerState;
    }
    public CultureInfo SelectedCulture
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsPersian)
            {
                var culture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");

                DateTimeFormatInfo formatInfo = culture.DateTimeFormat;
                formatInfo.AbbreviatedDayNames = ["ی", "د", "س", "چ", "پ", "ج", "ش"];
                formatInfo.DayNames = ["یکشنبه", "دوشنبه", "سه شنبه", "چهار شنبه", "پنجشنبه", "جمعه", "شنبه"];
                var monthNames = new[] { "فروردین", "اردیبهشت", "خرداد", "تیر", "مرداد", "شهریور", "مهر", "آبان", "آذر", "دی", "بهمن", "اسفند", "", };
                formatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames = formatInfo.MonthNames = formatInfo.MonthGenitiveNames = formatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = monthNames;
                formatInfo.AMDesignator = "ق.ظ";
                formatInfo.PMDesignator = "ب.ظ";
                formatInfo.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy/MM/dd";
                formatInfo.LongDatePattern = "dddd, dd MMMM,yyyy";
                formatInfo.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
                Calendar cal = new PersianCalendar();
                FieldInfo? fieldInfo = culture.GetType()?.GetField("calendar", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                fieldInfo?.SetValue(culture, cal);
                FieldInfo? info = formatInfo.GetType().GetField("calendar", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                info?.SetValue(formatInfo, cal);
                culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "/";
                culture.NumberFormat.DigitSubstitution = DigitShapes.NativeNational;
                culture.NumberFormat.NumberNegativePattern = 0;
                return culture;
            }
            return new CultureInfo("en-US");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works perfectly. But I still can't get why this causes the component to rerender

Comment: When Blazor renders a page, it first generates the expected DOM. Then, it compares it to the current DOM and applies the difference between the two so that the page conforms to what is expected.
When we have a collection and we display it with a foreach loop, if we add a member to the collection, everything that was displayed in the loop will be re-rendered and this is not optimized enough.
For such cases, we use key. The key informs Blazer to use the key for comparison.

more:
https://www.meziantou.net/optimizing-blazor-performance-using-the-key-directive.htm